# Having isssue while running instruments command

Tags: xcode, appium-ios

I'm having issue with `instruments -s devices` command in MacBook pro

```
admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro ~ % instruments -s devices  
zsh: command not found: instruments
```

the path of xcode is already set.
[image]

xcode-select --install also installed.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no "instruments" util in Xcode13, because of which when you run "instruments -s devices" , it will return **zsh: command not found: instruments**

Actually Apple recommends using xcrun xctrace instead of instruments in Xcode13.

So in xcode13 , below command will list all the devices

**xcrun xctrace list devices**

Comment: It took me around 10 days for finding the answer that the issue already solve but appreciate you answer thank you